# Update multi nested mongoDB schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema

This is my model schema

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("59999454bad567268f78dc09"),
"chapters" : [
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("59999454bad567268f78dc0a"), 
        "individualChapters" : [
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("59999454bad567268f78dc0b"), 
                "photos" : [
                    {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("59999454bad567268f78dc0c"),
                        image: ObjectId("599993e980c3ba2681639163")
                    }, 
                    { 
                        "_id" : ObjectId("59999595bad567268f78dc12"),
                        image: ObjectId("599993e980c3ba2681639163")
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5999957dbad567268f78dc10"), 
                "photos" : [
                    {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5999957dbad567268f78dc11"), 
                        image: ObjectId("599993e980c3ba2681639163")
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

i am trying to push another element in "photos" of second "individualChapters" using the below query, but its always pushing in "photos" of first "individualChapters".

```
Model.findAndModify(
{ 
    'chapters.individualChapters._id' : ObjectId("5999957dbad567268f78dc10"), 
    'chapters._id' : ObjectId("59999454bad567268f78dc0a"), 
    _id: ObjectId("59999454bad567268f78dc09") 
}, 
{
    '$push': { 
        'chapters.0.individualChapters.$.photos': { 
            image: ObjectId("599993e980c3ba2681639163")
        }
     }
}, { new: false, upsert: false })
```

Its always updating first individualChapters. Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to the wrong element. `$push` should have this

`chapters.0.individualChapters.1.photos.0._id` like this

Answer (score 0):

Here's what works in your specific case.

```
Model.findAndModify(
{
    'chapters.individualChapters._id' : ObjectId("5999957dbad567268f78dc10"), 
    'chapters._id' : ObjectId("59999454bad567268f78dc0a"), 
    '_id': ObjectId("59999454bad567268f78dc09")
},
{
    '$push': { 
        'chapters.0.individualChapters.1.photos': { 
            'image': ObjectId("599993e980c3ba2681639163")
        }
    }
}, { new: false, upsert: false })
```

Comment: How would i get to know the **index** "chapters.0.individualChapters. **1** .photos", I need to find the index on basis of
    {
        **'chapters.individualChapters._id' : ObjectId("5999957dbad567268f78dc10")**, 
        'chapters._id' : ObjectId("59999454bad567268f78dc0a"), 
        '_id': ObjectId("59999454bad567268f78dc09")
    }

That is why i used positional operator.

Comment: I was afraid that would be the case... ;) That is not possible, currently. You will need to load the document, change it in your application and save it back. The reason being that the positional operator can only appear once in an element name. That is a MongoDB limitation at this point.

Comment: Is it the right approach to find the complete document, change it in application and update complete document. The reason i designed it this way is because i will be implementing searching in this collection which could be at any level. Let me know if my approach is right?